# Angular ng-token-auth, post to wrong localhost

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails API running on http://localhost:3000/, and a Angular Front end running on http://localhost:8000/. I am implementing the Log in feature with ng-token-auth. It posts the token to the wrong localhost, which is the following one:

`http://localhost:8000/api/auth/sign_in`

I have spotted how to change every part of the URL, except the "http://localhost:8000/", that needs to be "http://localhost:3000/" can anybody hint me how with to do that please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#configuration), you should place the url in the config:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-token-auth'])
    .config(function($authProvider) {
        $authProvider.configure({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
        });
    });
```